# Bluetooth peripherals disconnect when on Microsoft Teams or Slack and using a Bluetooth Headset

Tags: audio, bluetooth, headphones, slack, ms-teams

I have noticed that whenever I join a Microsoft Teams call or a Slack huddle my bluetooth peripherals randomly lose connection.

I have a bluetooth headset connected (usually either Samsung WH noise cancelling headphones or AirPods Pro 2), a mouse (Logitech MX Master 3) and a keyboard (Logitech Mechanical Mini or Keychron K2), when the call starts within 30 seconds or so the keyboard disconnects completely (I have to tap the keys a few times to get to re-establish connection), mouse becomes laggy occasionally and sometimes the audio experiences a lag.

It almost feels like macOS is prioritising the headphones and disconnects everything else. All the devices are within a few inches of each other on a desk so I can't think it's interference. As soon as the call ends everything goes back to normal. Interestingly this is **not** an issue when I plug headphones to the AUX port. So looks like it's directly related to being on a call and using bluetooth headsets.

Has anyone experienced something like this? Can you suggest potential causes or fixes?

(I'm using a MacBook Pro with M1 Pro chip and 16GB of RAM, Ventura 13.2.1)

Comment: I’ve had my BT keyboard and mouse go into power saver mode while on a long call using BT headphones, but not after 30 seconds and it was initiated by the keyboard.  Tapping the space or moving the mouse brought them back to life after a couple of seconds.  How may BT peripherals do you have connected simultaneously?

Comment: Three at the same time. Keyboard, mouse and headphones.

Comment: I have a Keychron K8 BT keyboard.  When I’m operating off battery, it will go to sleep pretty quickly (not 30 seconds), but around 30 mins.  Tapping he keyboard will be laggy at first, then it’s back to normal.  Try keeping it plugged in to power only just to see if that is the issue.

Comment: Same results :/

Comment: I have noticed similar behavior myself. I use a Bluetooth mouse and headset, and whenever I am in a Teams call, the mouse gets super laggy. As soon as the call is over, the mouse starts working normally again.

My suspicions are definitely pointing at the BT connection itself, and not high CPU use. I cannot however pinpoint exactly where the issue lies yet.